# why there is unexpected value 6295648 come with answer 11110001 in output?here input is 241 and 2

Tags: c++

```
void base(int n,int b)
{
    int x[20],k=0;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        x[k]=n%b;
        n=n/b;
        k=k+1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=k;i++)
    {
        cout<<x[k-i];
    }
    return ;
}

int main()
{
    int number,baise;
    cin>>number;
    cin>>baise;
    base(number,baise); 
    return 0;
}
```

It is program of base expansion. I wrote a function for that and in `main()` I call it with 2 parameters (that I want to convert into another base) and baise (that is a base value into which a number is converted). The program runs and it also gives output but with the input it gives some undesirable values, which is 6295648 in this case.

Input:

```
241  
2
```

Output

```
629564811110001
```

But the output should be `11110001` only. I don't understand why the value `6295648` comes.

Comment: With 'i==0', you print `x[k]` that was never assigned. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an uninitialized object.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that `k` gets incremented **post** the assignment in the `x[]` array i.e. In the last iteration `k` gets incremented to `8`. Then in case of `k-i` when the value of `i` is 0 .. `x[k-i]` goes out of bounds.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void base(int n,int b)
{
    int x[20],k=-1;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        x[++k]=n%b; //pre increment
        n=n/b;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=k; i++)//now k contains the index of the last element
    {
        cout<<x[k-i];
    }
    return ;
}

int main()
{
    int number,baise;
    cin>>number;
    cin>>baise;
    base(number,baise); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<=k;i++)
{
    cout<<x[k-i];
}
```

At the first iteration of the loop, the executed statement is:

```
cout << x[k];
```

where `x[k]` is never assigned, which is an UB.

Changing the loop initialization statement to `x = 1` solves this problem. Or more clearly,

```
for(int i = k-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    cout << x[i];
}
```